# Automatically fixing of some pydocstyle errors?

Tags: python, automation, documentation

Pydocstyle is a piece of software that provides warnings for python docstrings. Some of these could easily be fixed by a computer

e.g.

- D209 Multi-line docstring closing quotes should be on a separate line
- D400 First line should end with a period
- D409 Section underline should match the length of its name
- And more

Is there any way, or a piece of software I can use to automatically fix this style of error? If necessary pydocstyle can provide file names and line numbers for errors.

Special note: I have found some software that can work with google style docstrings. I need specifically numpy style docstrings.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What you are asking die is ab software recommendation, and thus very opinion based. Your question is very likely to be closed. Maybe you get an answer over on the Software Recommendation StackExchange

Comment: @DarkDiamond What I'm trying to ask is if there are "any" that do it, or if there is another way. Do you have any suggestions to make that more clear?

Comment: *"Is there any way, or a piece of software I can use, to automatically fix some errors?"* - Yes, there are multiple automatic formatting tools for Python. However, you'll likely want to investigate these yourself, since only you know what will satisfy your needs in the long run.

Comment: @Anaksunaman "There are multiple automatic formatting tools for Python" Those are for code. Here I'm referring to docstrings. The only ones I've found are google or pep only.